# Jquery UI slider tooltip class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-slider

I'm having some trouble finding the css class linked to the tooltips in the Jquery ui slider... does anyone know what it's called, or another way I can adjust the tooltip width?

Comment: I am also looking to change the width of the tooltip.

Comment: jeez, I should have answered my own question. I figured it out but it was a while ago so I don't remember which class it was... I'm pretty sure that the width was not explicitly set, though, just the padding, so play around with that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a JSFiddle with your code?

You can see an example [JQueryUI Slider - Tooltip for the Current Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192442/jqueryui-slider-tooltip-for-the-current-position) where the tooltip is set with an id of "tooltip"

I modified a bit here http://jsfiddle.net/YShtg/1/

Maybe this will help out.