# JQueryUI Slider - Tooltip for the Current Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, tooltip

At the moment I have a slider and an small input text box which updates based on where you scroll on it.

Here is the javascript:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 500,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    step: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#budget").val(ui.value);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {}
});
$("#budget").val($("#slider").slider("value"));​
```

And here is the html/css:

```
<input type="text" id="budget" style="width:50px;text-align:center"/>

<div id="slider"></div>​
```

However it looks a bit odd having the small text box with the figure just at the top of the slider, so I would like it to update its horizontal position so it is above the handle of the slider (.ui-slider-handle) if possible - like a sort of tooltip.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need the input field or just a way to display the text, but you can show a tooltip like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bEze7/1/)**.

**jQuery**

```
var tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip" />').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: -10
}).hide();
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 500,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    step: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        tooltip.text(ui.value);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {}
}).find(".ui-slider-handle").append(tooltip).hover(function() {
    tooltip.show()
}, function() {
    tooltip.hide()
})​
```

Comment: This is what I am after, but with this implementation it is incredibly glitchy and intermittently disappears when dragging it.

Comment: How is it "incredibly glitchy"? In the demo, nothing disappears until you mouseout of the handle.

Comment: Oh Ive worked out what is happening - if you drag the handle too fast you ARE mousing out of the handle.

Comment: Awesome! though I think it's more efficient to use css to show/hide the tooltip

Comment: @MarkRobbo if it's important for the slider not to disappear, you can bind the show/hide to the slider's start and stop events instead of hover

Comment: Here is an implementation of the `start` and `stop` events for let appearing the tooltip: http://plnkr.co/edit/ydF3REsypFDlvz37fT4a?p=preview

Comment: This article shows how to create a slider where the value stays after the mouse has moved away.  You can move the mouse back and forth rapidly without glitches. [http://shout.setfive.com/2013/01/08/javascript-using-bootstrap-tooltips-with-jquery-uis-slider/](http://shout.setfive.com/2013/01/08/javascript-using-bootstrap-tooltips-with-jquery-uis-slider/)