# Trying to get Tooltip for the Current Position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a slider and an small input text box which updates based on where you scroll on it.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function() {
  
  var tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip" />').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: -10
}).hide();
    $("#client-slider").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 30,
      min: 15,
      max: 300,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('#client').val(ui.value).trigger("change");
           tooltip.text(ui.value);
      },
    change: function(event, ui) {}
}).find(".ui-slider-handle").append(tooltip).hover(function() {
    tooltip.show();
}, function() {
    tooltip.hide();
});
    });
    $("#client").val($("#client-slider").slider("value"));
  }
```

And here is the html/css:

```
<input type="text" id="client" style="width:50px;text-align:center"/>
<div id="slider"></div>​
```

I am getting an error could not able to show tool tip on my slider

**Plz note its not the duplicate of any existing question - I was trying to get help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192442/jqueryui-slider-tooltip-for-the-current-position) but all in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often a bad idea to get answers from old posts. This implementation is much more up to date and much less complicated:

```js
document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("budget").value = event.target.value;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="budget" style="width:50px;text-align:center"/>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="15" max="300" value="15"/>
```

Full code:

```
<input type="text" id="budget" style="width:50px;text-align:center"/>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="15" max="300" value="15"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        document.getElementById("budget").value = event.target.value;
    })
</script>
```

For the **JQUERY implementation** based off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11192837/12415287):

```js
    var tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip" />').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: -10
}).hide();

$("#slider").slider({
    value: 500,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    step: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        tooltip.text((ui.value/1000)*100 + "%");
        $( "#client" ).val((ui.value/1000)*100 + "%");
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {}
}).find(".ui-slider-handle").append(tooltip).hover(function() {
    tooltip.show()
}, function() {
    tooltip.hide()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="text" id="client" style="width:50px;text-align:center"/>
<div id="slider" style="margin:50px"></div>
<!-- Get ajax -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Try it on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spzxyjeq/8/) as well.

Comment: Thanks @Prosy Basically I cant use this -- I already used Divs and jquery-ui slider -- A lot of dependencies so cant switch to any new solution -- Is there any way you can modify my code ? I just want tool tip over the slider dot

Comment: @SkillUp this really had me. I didn't know there was supposed to be another import for jqueryui. Haven't used it ever. But its good now.

Comment: Thanks so much Sir , Any way we can convert it into percentage based on the min /max values ? would be helpful if you reply on it :)

Comment: Updated the answer to make the values percentages

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x7a1ksjr/  I am trying to get 1-100 percentage according to my value but its going upto 30% only

Comment: The max for the slider is only at 300. make it 1000 to be consistent with the divisor.